# Find Value of Map while Ignoring Case - A Better Solution?

Tags: java

I have a `Map` that holds a List of `Objects`. These Objects will be a mix of Strings, Integers, and Doubles. I'm using Apache Commons `DualHashBidiMap` to get use out of the `containsValue()` method, which grabs the `Map` value based on the List of Objects passed to it.

```
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>
// populate list ...
BidiMap map = new DualHashBidiMap()
map.put(3, list)
if(map.containsValue(list)){
    // do stuff 
}
```

This works fine except for when there are differences in casing within the List. i.e., "Username" is not equal to "username". Is there a simple way to ignore casing during every check or am I tied to converting each String `toLower()` and *then* comparing?

Perhaps there's another `Map` I'm overlooking that can achieve this

Comment: String has an equalsIgnoreCase method... Don't use != for strings

Comment: Converting the String to a known case a simple approach.

Comment: @cricket_007 I'm not using != that was pseudocode.

Comment: Do you need to use a `Map`? Since `List` also comes with `contains` method to check for exists check.

Comment: @Sachin I'm using a `Map` to retrieve Keys as well as eliminating duplicates

Comment: Is every object a mix of String, Integer and Double or is it either of these? Maybe you should create an explicit Object which can only be one of them, and enforce lowercase in the ctor, if it happens to be a String. Or you override equals and hashcode for your Mapobject.

Comment: I don't know if there is a specific `Map` implementation. Here the problem is  the `equals` of  `String`, you should force to use the `equalsIgnoreCase`. Maybe extending the String class by overriding the `equals` and the `hash` methods to ignore case. But, in this case, I think that it should be easier to check the type of the `Object` and, if `String`, just `toLower()` on it.